# Bootstrap and IE7

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would I be correct in concluding that Bootstrap does not support IE7?
Are there any CSS or JS tricks to get around it?

I have tried a few different experiments using both emulation and an actual IE7 browser with the following results.

Default Visual Studio MVC template (3.0.0), note the form labels and login button.
[image]

Bootstrap Website (3.3.4), note the large navbar
[image]

Default Visual Studio Template Upgraded to 3.3.4, now we have the large navar and the badly formatted form.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, i would either go with bootstrap 2 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ it isn't supported any more but you should be fine or try a poly fill like https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7 but bear in mind the latter is in beta and might be a little buggy